# Using Zend\Dom\Query

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-dom-query

I am useing Zend\Dom\Query to get specific content from a webpage.

This is the html:

```
<div class="menuName darkGreen leftMenu">
   <a href="index.php?ref=MjBfMDJfMDZfMTRfMV8x">Mouse</a>
</div>
```

How can I get the value **Mouse** ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dom = new \Zend\Dom\Query($html);
$results = $dom->execute('div.menuName a');
$doc = $results->current();
var_dump($doc->nodeValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is working. I would like to know more about this `current()` function. I need the documentation. I have another problem like below

<br/>

`<div class="logo_left">
   <a href="http://www.abc.com">
      <img alt="abc" data-cfsrc="abc" src="**http://www.abc.com/logo.jpg**">
   </a>
</div>`

<br/>

I would like to catch img src attribute.

<br/>

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$doc->getAttribute('src');
```